# Display image on all SSRS report multiple pages that are dynamically generated

Tags: .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to display database image on all the pages of the report. I have a parameter which takes a string of id's and generate multiple pages. When using this input string multiple pages are created but the image is not getting displayed. One more optional input parameter that accepts single id which generates one page and displays the image. For multiple id's string parameter multiple pages are displayed but not the logo header. Please help.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Is the image in a header and you are asking why the header is not visible on multiple pages?

Comment: Hi Ross, yes image in the header..I solved this by making the image static which appears on all the report pages instead getting the image from the database when taking string of id's